# Oracle regexp_substr hierarchal

Tags: regex, oracle, hierarchical-data

I thought I understood regular expressions until today.

(I also posted this on OTN but I think there's a wider audience on stackoverflow)

I have a column which contains a mess of codes, and a second column that gives a slight hint of how the hierarchy is supposed to be.

```
CREATE TABLE REGEXTEST
  ( ITEM VARCHAR(200),LEV INT);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4',1);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-1',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-10',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-11',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-12',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-13',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-14',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-15',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-15-59A7',3);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-15-59D7',3);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-15-59F7',3);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('4245-4-15-5987',3);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('1090-81/5285',1);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('1090-81/5285-20',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('1090-81/5285-30',2);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('1090-81/5285-30-5',3);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('1090-81/5285-30-5/20',3);

  INSERT INTO REGEXTEST (ITEM,LEV) VALUES ('1090-81/5285-30-6/25',3);
```

I need to build a hierarchy of parent/child where the parent is determined by the level. To complicate matters, sometimes there's a slash / separating the levels and sometimes there's a hyphen. but the hyphen and dashes don't necessarily mean a change in level.

I'll explain the simplest scenario (with the 4245 sample data).

4245-4 is level one. All good.
4245-4-1 is a level 2. So the name of the child is 4245-4-1 and its parent is 4245-1. I'd like the result to be  ParentColumn,ChildColumn. I'm building a directory structure with this data. So to continue with the same example:

```
Parent  Child

4245-4

4245-4  4245-4-1

4245-4  4245-4-10

4245-4  4245-4-11

4245-4  4245-4-12

4245-4  4245-4-15

4245-4-15   4245-4-15-59A7

4245-4-15   4245-4-15-59D7

4245-4-15   4245-4-15-59F7
```

For the more complicated example now (with / involved)

```
Parent  Child

1090-81

1090-81 1090-81/5285

1090-81/52851090-81/5285-20

1090-81/5285    1090-81/5285-30

1090-81/5285-30 1090-81/5285-30-5

1090-81/5285-30 1090-81/5285-30-5/20

1090-81/5285-30 1090-81/5285-30-6/25
```

there isn't a determined maximum number of levels. I think the current max I see is 6 but that could change I suppose.

Comment: Why is 1090-81 a root, rather than 1090-81/5285 ? And is the `lev` column relevant, or is that just to show us which level you expect each value to be?

Comment: The level is relevant as it'll give you a hint as to where the break is however the text might break on / or - ... unfortunately there's no logic to that.

Comment: But why is "1090-81" listed in your sample results at all?  It is not in the sample data you provided.  Are you simply deducing it from the existence of "1090-81/5285"?  Aside from this node that appears made up, the slashes seem irrelevant to the level in the data you've provide.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to follow are hierarchical queries. The following query represents a first approximation (pending the answer to AlexPoole's question):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (
              SELECT (SELECT (max(lev)) FROM regextest) - LEVEL  lvl
                   , SUBSTR(item, 1, INSTR(item,'-',-1)-1)       parent
                   , item                                        child
                FROM regextest
          START WITH lev = (SELECT (max(lev)) FROM regextest)
          CONNECT BY PRIOR SUBSTR(item, 1, INSTR(item,'-',-1)- 1) = item
         )
   WHERE lvl > 0
order by child
       ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have some understanding of regex (and you even named the table regextest), here is a solution that uses regex  -

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM (    SELECT PRIOR item AS parentitem, item
              FROM regextest
        CONNECT BY PRIOR lev = lev - 1
               AND REGEXP_SUBSTR (item,
                                  '([0-9A-Z/-]+)([-])([0-9A-Z/]+)',
                                  1,
                                  1,
                                  'i',
                                  1) = PRIOR item)
   WHERE parentitem IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY item;
```

The regex splits the 'item' string into 3 parts:

1. [everything until the last hyphen],
2. [the last hyphen in the item string] and
3. [everything after the last hyphen].

I'm sure you can write a cleaner regex for doing the same thing.

And then just match the first subpart to the 'PRIOR item' in connect by. The prior item matched until the last hyphen is the parent.
The first subpart can be extracted in regex_substr from the 6th parameter, 1 in this case.

You can omit the part in the connect by clause that says

```
PRIOR lev = lev - 1
```

as that is just for semantics and doesn't add any value. Probably worse to keep it as bad data in that column can mess up the results.

Also, as the other answer pointed out, Alex Poole's question still stands. Why do you have 1090-81 in the example as a row when it is not in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Someone I asked from a group I belong to came up with the following answer:

```
SELECT    p.item     AS parent
,         c.item     AS child
,         c.lev
FROM             regextext  c
LEFT  JOIN  regextext p  ON   p.lev    = c.lev - 1 
AND  REPLACE (c.item, '-', '/' )
LIKE REPLACE (p.item, '-', '/') || '/%';
```

It took 86 minutes to run against my real data but the results were exactly what I was looking for.